# How to force WordPress Gutenberg to update the featured image after saving the post?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am working on a plugin that automatically attaches a featured image to a WordPress post after save (i.e. programmatically not using the Media Selector). The plugin uses the `add_action( 'save_post_post', 'myFunction');` hook to save the image to the post.

The Gutenberg UI does not update the featured image thumbnail in the metabox on the right column.

I have tested and verified that the image is successfully updated and attached to the post, and does show if you manually reload the page.

From what I can tell, I need to tell Gutenberg the featured image has been changed in order for it to be updated in the view.

I have been unable to locate a hook or action I can use to trigger such a refresh after the user presses the "Save" button.

What is the appropriate way accomplish this refresh (from within my plugin PHP file)?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, WordPress takes care of the update for you. Maybe you didn't use the right hook?

When I use the following, my posts have a default thumbnail, whenever I open a new plugin page:

```
 function custom_add_thumbnail( $post_ID ) {
    set_post_thumbnail($post_ID, 67);
    return $post_ID;
 }

add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_add_thumbnail' );
```

If this doesn't help, please share your code, maybe in pastebin, so I can investigate further.